# K-fold Cross validation in Transformer-like model with epoch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation, transformers

I'm new to Transformer and am building a Transformer model for classification. Before I added the k-fold validation, **I needed 3 epochs to train the model**.

Here comes the question: say, if I use 5-fold cross validation, do I train 5 models in total, one for every 3 epochs. OR Do I use 5-fold cross validation under every epoch ?

How do I aggregate the test loss if I was training 5 different models ?
After the k-fold is done, how do I know which model to save, I am quite confused here..
Please explain the things in English...